# JS adding equals sign (=) after valueless url query parameters when deleting the query params

Tags: javascript

I have one url which will have one query param for eg `https://stackoverflow.com/questions?hello=1`, i am deleting this param without checking if it is present or not and pushing to the current location using `pushState` function

if the `hello=1` param is not present and if we trying to delete this param without checking is present and if the url contain different valueless parameter for eg `https://stackoverflow.com/questions?test` the equal to sign in append to end of the parameter

Example Snippet 1  - Deleting the parameter in url without checking the existence of parameter and also its contain one valueless parameter

```js
var currentURL = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tes");
var currentURLSearchParams = currentURL.searchParams;

console.log("urlBefore:", currentURL)

currentURLSearchParams.delete("hello")

console.log("urlAfter:", currentURL)
```

Example Snippet 2 - Deleting the parameter in the url with checking the existence of parameter and also it contain one valueless parameter

```js
var currentURL = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tes");
var currentURLSearchParams = currentURL.searchParams;

console.log("urlBefore:", currentURL)


var helloParameter = currentURLSearchParams.get("hello") 
if (helloParameter) {
   currentURLSearchParams.delete("hello")
}


console.log("urlAfter:", currentURL)
```

Snippet 1 Result:

```
urlBefore: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tes"
urlAfter: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tes="
```

Snippet 2 Result:

```
urlBefore: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tes"
urlAfter: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tes"
```

By checking the parameter existence the url did not get appended with `=` sign at end

can any one help me to understand this functionality.

Comment: I don't think it's valid to have a query parameter without `=`?

Comment: For instance, using `URLSearchParams` you cannot set a param without the value. `const u = URLSearchParams(); u.set('tes'); // throws error`

Comment: @evolutionxbox in the case i am not setting the any params using `searchparams.set()` method

Comment: I'm not saying you are. I'm showing that using standard objects/methods will not allow us to set a parameter without a value.